# How to trigger without any string in auto completion

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, tinymce, tinymce-5

We need a help on tinymce editor , we build a auto completion using https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/autocompleter/#, but we need to change null trigger, we need to get auto suggestions on first Letter typing. Please help me to fix this issue.

We are using a @ trigger to see auto suggestions, we need with not triggered using.

Answer (score 1):

So to confirm, when you use the @ trigger, it's not showing the list of suggested text to include in the text area?

To get the auto suggestions to appear on the very first letter of typing, set `minChars: 1,` as this option specifies the minimum number of characters to type. I'm not sure if setting it to 0 will change the behaviour.

This blog post has another example of using the auto completer if that helps: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-configure-the-autocompleter-api-card-menu-items/